# Same ClientID required on Subscription

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jms, ibm-mq

How to start two subscription topics with same clientID in tomcat setup. Currently, I have started topic with different clientID on two servers and getting two messages which is correct behavior

```
Topic Connection in context.xml

HOST="hostname" PORT="port" CHAN="channel" TRAN="1" SCPHS="cipher" QMGR="QManager"  CID="PERFTEST" BSUB="" CCSUB="" CLS="1" BPUB="" BCON="" BVER="2" PVER="8" />
```

I thought CLONESUPP will be able to help like this "When a message is published on the subscription's topic, a copy of that message is sent to the subscription. The message is available to any of the consumers, but only one receives it".

I tried adding CLS in topic connection, but it didn't worked

Comment: What error do you receive when you use the same client ID?

Comment: @JoshMc I received below error on other server. 

2023-10-27 08:53:42,358 [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] WARN  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer- Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic://UK_ENV83/PRV_TCACHE/SED/SOPHISML/PS_FOLIO/POSITION?brokerCCDurSubQueue=SYSTEM.JMS.D.CC.GB_RCSX&brokerDurSubQueue=SYSTEM.JMS.D.GB_RCSX' - trying to recover. Cause: Broker command failed: 3157 Reason code 3157

Comment: Topic Connection on both servers. 

HOST="" PORT="" CHAN="" TRAN="1" SCPHS="" QMGR=""  CID="XCS-PERFTEST" BSUB="" CCSUB="" CLS="1" BPUB="" BCON=""  BVER="2" PVER="6" /

Comment: MQ Version: 9.3.0.10

Comment: It worked with removing BVER="2" PVER="6", but our middleware team has recommended to used broker version 2 and provider version 6. 
How does it impact Cloned subscription?

Comment: Those were not available in provider version 6. It was added at 7.

Comment: thanks @JoshMc. Open new question thread for provider version 8.